# Integration GitKraken with university self-hosted GitLab on subdirectory

Tags: git, dns, gitlab, host, gitkraken

I have problem with authentication my university's self-hosted GitLab using GitKraken. This GitLab is not putted on unique host like gitlab.domain.com but on domain.com/gitlab
It is possible to connect self-hosted GitLab with GitKraken using link like this above? Because when I just type it on Host domain input it's not working. I generated a Personal Token.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [Pro (paid)](https://www.gitkraken.com/pricing) version of GitKraken? [Integration with self-hosted instances of GitLab require a Pro license](https://www.gitkraken.com/git-client#integrations).

You can still use the repository functions with the free version.

Comment: I have. I wrote about specific gitlab hostname like domain.com/gitlab